# Accessing the store, without triggering data reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application I am forcing a `App.Nodes.find()` early (in `ApplicationRoute.setupController`) since I need to access the nodes in all of my routes. To get a node I have this application method:

```
var App = Ember.Application.createWithMixins({
    ...
    getNode: function (nodeId) {
        var nodes = this.Node.find();
        var node = nodes.findProperty('id', nodeId);
        return node;
    },
    ...
});
```

But this is triggering a request, every time. To avoid this, I have been keeping a `rawNodes` cache:

```
cacheNodes : function () {
    this.set('rawNodes', this.Node.find());
},
```

But I do not like to keep a separate cache than the one that ember has in the store, because this forces me to manually keep it synchronized.

I want to re-use the data in the store and not request new data. How can I access the `nodes` store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you have different options.

For example you could access the store's cache with `.all()` to avoid triggering a request, for example:

```
var App = Ember.Application.createWithMixins({
  ...
  getNode: function (nodeId) {
    var nodes = this.Node.all();
    var node = nodes.findProperty('id', nodeId);
    return node;
  },
  ...
});
```

Depending from where you need access to your nodes, for example from another controller you could also access your nodes using the `needs` API, something like this:

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'nodes',
  nodesContentBinding: 'controllers.nodes.content',
  someMethod: function() {
    this.get('nodesContent');
  }
});
```

Or even another approach beeing in a route:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  someMethod: function() {
    this.controllerFor('nodes').get('content');
  }
});
```

All this approaches would not trigger any request at all accessing your already existent nodes in your application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I like the first method. The other methods depend on having a nodes controller, which is not necessarily the case. I have it, but I could very well just have the node model, without controller (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @gonvalex, if you haven't defined an explicit nodes controller then ember will create automatically one for you, so you have it either way :)

Comment: Any idea how to access the nodes in the store from a template? I have tried with `{{view SettingsApp.Select2SelectView contentBinding="App.controllers.nodes.content" ...}}` but this is not working. Before I had `contentBinding="App.rawNodes"`

Comment: @gonvaled, if the `view` from where your are trying this has a controller with the nodes controller dependency defined with the needs API then a simple `contentBinding="controllers.nodes.content` should work.

Comment: Strange. The `controllers.nodes.content` is empty, even though the nodes index is working fine. Do I have to manually set the content of the controller, or does it get automatically set up by ember? This is my `App.NodesIndexRoute.model: function () { return App.Node.find(); }`

Comment: Found it! I need to access `controllers.nodesIndex.content` and do `needs: : 'nodesIndex'`. So many little variations ... Confusing :( Thanks anyway!